# jQuery validation on date field

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, jquery, content-editor-web-part

I have 2 date fields in SharePoint list `Deferral Raised Date` and `Original Dispatch to date`.

I want to put formula in jQuery such that value of `Original Dispatch to date` should be less than `Deferral Raised Date` i.e.

```
[Original Dispatch to date]<[Deferral Raised Date].
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with jquery

```
var Original_Dispatch= new Date($('#startDate').val());
var Deferral_Raised= new Date($('#endDate').val());

if (Original_Dispatch< Deferral_Raised){

// Do something

}
```

Comment: I added below query in CEWP but not working:  <script type="text/javascript">

 function PreSaveAction() 
{ 

var Original_Dispatch= new Date($('Original Dispatch to NOC date').val());
var Deferral_Raised= new Date($('Deferral Raised Date').val());

if (Original_Dispatch< Deferral_Raised)
{

alert("test error");
return false;
}

return true;
 }
</script>​

Comment: Hi ARD I used same code in fiddler .Its working in it.https://jsfiddle.net/t5on6wbq/.......I think your PreSave action is not getting called